# Display geom_label just for mean values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd really appreciate your help. I simply want to display a mean value at each time point for 2 treatment groups (corresponding the the red line). I've tried with geom_label but it seems to label every single point. Any idea how to label just the means (i.e. 4 value labels in treatment group A and 4 in treatment group B).

[image]

```
# Assign random alpha (0 [50%] or 1 [50%]) values
dat <-  ddply(dat, .(id), function(x){
  x$alpha = ifelse(runif(n = 1) > 0.50, 1, 0)
  x
})
# Plot
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = week, y = iop, group = id)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(alpha=alpha, group=id)) +
  guides(alpha=FALSE) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = "point", fun.y = mean, size = 3, color = "red") +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size = 2, color = "red") +
  geom_label(stat = 'summary', fun.y=mean, aes(label = round(..y.., 2)), nudge_x = 0.1, hjust = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,18,6)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ trt) +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Month") + ylab("IOP")
```

Comment: `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="label", aes(label=round(..y.., 2))`

Comment: stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="label", aes(group=1, label=round(..y.., 1)))